# Git - Undo forced checkout from IntelliJ IDE

Tags: git, github

I had some uncommitted changes in my local, by mistake, I did force checkout instead of smart checkout in IntelliJ

Is there any way to revert back?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, you can try restoring from its [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html).

Comment: Had you staged your changes. If yes, then you can get them back. Otherwise I'm afraid there's no hope.

Comment: @Deshak9 Do you used from `git stash` ?

Comment: @Deshak9 you can use `git log` and then `git checkout <commit_ID>`

Comment: @yeputons, thank you Sir, that helped. Curious, if can we do it using Git

Comment: @hspandher, Unfortunately I didn't :(

Answer (score 23):

The only way is to open [VCS → Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) menu and revert to a state which was before your Forced Checkout.

**Important things to notice:**

1. Be sure to select the whole project folder first, otherwise you would be looking at Local History for only currently active file.
2. You will revert to the state that was before your checkout, which means you would have to extract lost changelist files through a lot of rubbish.

Comment: This is a life-save and also very helpful side notes 

Comment: Life-saving tip.  Thank you!